# All Memory Not showing up with Ubuntu-64 bit

Tags: 12.04, hardware, memory

I am only showing 5.8GB out of 9GB:

```
harrison@harrison-Aurora:~/Desktop$ lshw -C memory
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
 *-memory                
   description: System memory
   physical id: 0
   size: 5961MiB
```

But when I run lshw -C memory it show all 9GB:

```
[sudo] password for harrison: 
*-firmware              
   description: BIOS
   vendor: Alienware
   physical id: 0
   version: A10
   date: 07/30/2010
   size: 64KiB
   capacity: 4032KiB
   // other stuff here
   *-memory
   description: System Memory
   physical id: a
   slot: System board or motherboard
   size: 9GiB
        *-bank:0
      description: DIMM 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
      product: KP223C-ELD
      vendor: Kingston
      physical id: 0
      serial: 43791B85
      slot: DIMM0
      size: 2GiB
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
 *-bank:1
      description: DIMM 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
      product: KTW149-ELD
      vendor: Kingston
      physical id: 1
      serial: B0953279
      slot: DIMM1
      size: 1GiB
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
 *-bank:2
      description: DIMM 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
      product: KP223C-ELD
      vendor: Kingston
      physical id: 2
      serial: 7A381B2B
      slot: DIMM2
      size: 2GiB
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
 *-bank:3
      description: DIMM 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
      product: KTW149-ELD
      vendor: Kingston
      physical id: 3
      serial: B0E63277
      slot: DIMM3
      size: 1GiB
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
 *-bank:4
      description: DIMM 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
      product: KP223C-ELD
      vendor: Kingston
      physical id: 4
      serial: 7A3B1B2B
      slot: DIMM4
      size: 2GiB
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
 *-bank:5
      description: DIMM 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
      product: KTW149-ELD
      vendor: Kingston
      physical id: 5
      serial: B0BF3277
      slot: DIMM5
      size: 1GiB
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
```

How can I go about using all 9GB?

Comment: You have two different models of RAM. Try putting the same models in the same matched pair slots. This means put the KP223C-ELD into DIMM0, DIMM1 and DIMM2; and the  KTW149-ELD into the other DIMM positions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two different models of RAM. Try putting the same models in the same matched pair slots. This means put the KP223C-ELD into DIMM0, DIMM1 and DIMM2; and the KTW149-ELD into the other DIMM positions.

Answer (score 0):

I got all 9GB to show up. Here is what I did:

1. Place 2GB modules into banks 0, 1, 2
2. Place 1GB modules in banks 3, 4, 5

Comment: Good. Are you okay for me to post my comment as an answer and then you accept it?

Comment: Yes. Go ahead and post your answer.